# How can I perform something similar to forEach() but using next line?

Tags: javascript, node.js, foreach, newline

If I use the following code:

```
let original = "http://www.spur-g-shop.de/index.php?action=buy_now&BUYproducts_id=56&
http://associations.beauvais.fr/en-un-clic/index.php?option=com_fabrik&view=list&listid=4&Itemid=520&asso_annuaireweb___id_soustheme_raw=40&sous_theme___ID_Theme=SPORTS&resetfilters=1
http://laptopbank.net/product_detail.php?detail_id=B075FLBJV7
https://www.music-scores.com/sheet-music/freeinstrument.php?instrument=Alto%20Sax
http://www.traxjo.com/index.php?PageType=2&MenuID=1&Sub=1&Lang=1
http://www.bizfocus.co.kr/admin/bbs/down.php?code=data&idx=8928&no=1
http://www.vivitekthailand.com/en/Product_view.php?ProductId=115&CategoryId=7
http://www.fsrm.ch/doc/c474.php?lang=e&id=474
https://catalog.prm-catalog.com/index.php?lang=tw&ID=18&CatalogID=2839
https://astacology.org/AboutCrayfish.asp?uid=Guest"
```

assuming that each new line is \n of course

and I run this code:

```
let dorks = original.split('/').pop().split('?')[0];
console.log(dorks)
```

it only returns:

index.php (as for the first url)

How can I make it return for each line all together?

Comment: You're splitting on `?` and then only capturing the first element of the split array `[0]`. What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: Split on a new line, then use a `.forEach` or a normal loop, or `.map` to just perform the same operation with each URL.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a `forEach` that'll do it for you:

```js
    //note the use of a backtick here to allow your new line characters in string
    let original = `http://www.spur-g-shop.de/index.php?action=buy_now&BUYproducts_id=56&
    http://associations.beauvais.fr/en-un-clic/index.php?option=com_fabrik&view=list&listid=4&Itemid=520&asso_annuaireweb___id_soustheme_raw=40&sous_theme___ID_Theme=SPORTS&resetfilters=1
    http://laptopbank.net/product_detail.php?detail_id=B075FLBJV7
    https://www.music-scores.com/sheet-music/freeinstrument.php?instrument=Alto%20Sax
    http://www.traxjo.com/index.php?PageType=2&MenuID=1&Sub=1&Lang=1
    http://www.bizfocus.co.kr/admin/bbs/down.php?code=data&idx=8928&no=1
    http://www.vivitekthailand.com/en/Product_view.php?ProductId=115&CategoryId=7
    http://www.fsrm.ch/doc/c474.php?lang=e&id=474
    https://catalog.prm-catalog.com/index.php?lang=tw&ID=18&CatalogID=2839
    https://astacology.org/AboutCrayfish.asp?uid=Guest`

    //split on newline, and then for each URL, grab everything before the ? and trim extra spaces
    original.split("\n").forEach((url)=> console.log(url.split("?")[0].replace(/ /g,'')));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let original = `http://www.spur-g-shop.de/index.php?action=buy_now&BUYproducts_id=56&
http://associations.beauvais.fr/en-un-clic/index.php?option=com_fabrik&view=list&listid=4&Itemid=520&asso_annuaireweb___id_soustheme_raw=40&sous_theme___ID_Theme=SPORTS&resetfilters=1
http://laptopbank.net/product_detail.php?detail_id=B075FLBJV7
https://www.music-scores.com/sheet-music/freeinstrument.php? instrument=Alto%20Sax
http://www.traxjo.com/index.php?PageType=2&MenuID=1&Sub=1&Lang=1
http://www.bizfocus.co.kr/admin/bbs/down.php?code=data&idx=8928&no=1
http://www.vivitekthailand.com/en/Product_view.php?ProductId=115&CategoryId=7
http://www.fsrm.ch/doc/c474.php?lang=e&id=474
https://catalog.prm-catalog.com/index.php?lang=tw&ID=18&CatalogID=2839
https://astacology.org/AboutCrayfish.asp?uid=Guest`

original.split(/\s/).map(w => w.split('?')[0])
/* returns [
     "http://www.spur-g-shop.de/index.php", 
     "http://associations.beauvais.fr/en-un-clic/index.php",
     "http://laptopbank.net/product_detail.php",
     "https://www.music-scores.com/sheet-music/freeinstrument.php",
     "http://www.traxjo.com/index.php",
     "http://www.bizfocus.co.kr/admin/bbs/down.php",
     "http://www.vivitekthailand.com/en/Product_view.php",
     "http://www.fsrm.ch/doc/c474.php",
     "https://catalog.prm-catalog.com/index.php",
     "https://astacology.org/AboutCrayfish.asp"
   ] */
```

the `/\s/`is a Regular Expression which detects all kinds of white spaces. After creating an array from your string by splitting at the positions of all white spaces you can then split again each value by the `'?'` which you already did.

Make sure the scheme of the string is exactly like that. Otherwise this script might throw an error.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely certain how you wish to display the matches but here is how you can avoid looping:

```js
let original = `http://www.spur-g-shop.de/index.php?action=buy_now&BUYproducts_id=56&
http://associations.beauvais.fr/en-un-clic/index.php?option=com_fabrik&view=list&listid=4&Itemid=520&asso_annuaireweb___id_soustheme_raw=40&sous_theme___ID_Theme=SPORTS&resetfilters=1
http://laptopbank.net/product_detail.php?detail_id=B075FLBJV7
https://www.music-scores.com/sheet-music/freeinstrument.php?instrument=Alto%20Sax
http://www.traxjo.com/index.php?PageType=2&MenuID=1&Sub=1&Lang=1
http://www.bizfocus.co.kr/admin/bbs/down.php?code=data&idx=8928&no=1
http://www.vivitekthailand.com/en/Product_view.php?ProductId=115&CategoryId=7
http://www.fsrm.ch/doc/c474.php?lang=e&id=474
https://catalog.prm-catalog.com/index.php?lang=tw&ID=18&CatalogID=2839
https://astacology.org/AboutCrayfish.asp?uid=Guest`;

let re = /[^.\/]+\.(?:php|asp)/g;

console.log(original.match(re));
console.log(original.match(re).join(' '));
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several way to obtain what you want. Assuming the minimal change of code, your problem is just apply your logic on multiple lines.

So the easiest way is just split the strings using the new line as delimiter, and then apply for each of them the code you already wrote:

```js
let s = `http://www.spur-g-shop.de/index.php?action=buy_now&BUYproducts_id=56&
http://associations.beauvais.fr/en-un-clic/index.php?option=com_fabrik&view=list&listid=4&Itemid=520&asso_annuaireweb___id_soustheme_raw=40&sous_theme___ID_Theme=SPORTS&resetfilters=1
http://laptopbank.net/product_detail.php?detail_id=B075FLBJV7
https://www.music-scores.com/sheet-music/freeinstrument.php?instrument=Alto%20Sax
http://www.traxjo.com/index.php?PageType=2&MenuID=1&Sub=1&Lang=1
http://www.bizfocus.co.kr/admin/bbs/down.php?code=data&idx=8928&no=1
http://www.vivitekthailand.com/en/Product_view.php?ProductId=115&CategoryId=7
http://www.fsrm.ch/doc/c474.php?lang=e&id=474
https://catalog.prm-catalog.com/index.php?lang=tw&ID=18&CatalogID=2839
https://astacology.org/AboutCrayfish.asp?uid=Guest`;

let dorks = s.split("\n").map(url => url.split('/').pop().split('?')[0]);

console.log(dorks)
```

Notice the usage of the [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) in order to easily got the new line.

As you can see the main logic is exactly the same you wrote (`url.split("/").pop().split("?")[0]`) it's just applied for each line using [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

You might solve this issue using a regular expression, but I think it would be beneficial to you understand how to apply the same logic on multiple line (therefore you can easily change the function you pass to `map` if the logic changes.

Answer (score 0):

```
let mapped = original.split('\n').map(o => o.split('/').pop().split('?')[0])
```

Worked fine, I split at new line and mapped the function!

Comment: If a particular answer helped you to achieve this result then consider accepting it using the checkmark next to the answer and just add your final solution as a comment.